# hdparm succeeds reading sector but cp does not

Tags: hard-disk, hdparm

I have a drive where I want to copy data from but `cp` fails every time and prints:

```
cp: error reading 'path/to/always/same/file': Input/output error
```

The output of `dmesg` contains:

```
[72481.869510] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[72481.874133] ata2.01: configured for UDMA/133
[72481.874145] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[72481.874147] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdc] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[72481.874149] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdc] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[72481.874152] sd 1:0:1:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 f7 9f 4c 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[72481.874154] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 4154412112
[72481.879316] ata2: EH complete
[72484.819205] ata2.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[72484.824273] ata2.01: failed command: READ DMA EXT
[72484.829346] ata2.01: cmd 25/00:08:50:4c:9f/00:00:f7:00:00/f0 tag 0 dma 4096 in
                        res 51/40:00:50:4c:9f/40:00:f7:00:00/10 Emask 0x9 (media error)                                             
[72484.849742] ata2.01: status: { DRDY ERR }
[72484.854836] ata2.01: error: { UNC }
```

After reading up on the problem online, I learned that this means that I manually have to mark a bad block as such. But issuing read command does not return "fail":

```
$ sudo hdparm --read-sector 4154412112 /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
reading sector 4154412112: SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 03 00 00 00 00 0a 40 51 10 00 11 04 00 00 a0 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
succeeded
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried ddrescue?

Comment: The hdparm output looks like an failure ("bad sense data"), even if you see "succeeded". Try the sg tools discussed [here](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto)

Comment: @RafaelKitover I have no run `dd` and `ddrescue` on it. However, I'm unsure as to how to interpret the output. Anyway, here it is: https://pastebin.com/k9XRqW3d

Comment: @meuh I took the number of bytes where `dd` aborted (not the original broken region but there seem to be more than one), divided it by 512, and got the number `4154412112`. Then I ran the following: https://pastebin.com/e6uMDZzC Google apparently does not know anything about the error message "READ DEFECT DATA(10): Illegal request, invalid opcode". Do you think that it means my hard drive does not support marking bad blocks as such?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact meaning of the messages, but the ddrescue shows there were 3 clusters of unreadable data, and there is no way to replace the bad blocks with spare blocks on the disk. I'm not even sure that you would be able to overwrite the bad sectors, which can fix some read errors.

Answer (score 2):

`hdparm` succeeded in *talking with the drive*¹. That's all “succeeded” indicates. The drive said “SG_IO: bad/missing sense data”. I don't know exactly what this means², but it's definitely not a good thing. **`hdparm` did not succeed in reading the sector**.

`hdparm` went ahead and displayed the memory buffer which is supposed to contain the sector content, but that's all zeros. It's clearly not something that was read from the drive.

Marking that block as bad may help to continue working with the drive for a bit, although of course you should replace it as soon as possible. (However the bad block should have been marked as such automatically. I don't see why you'd do that manually.) But it isn't going to let you read the data from that block.

¹  <sub>Specifically, it means that the [`HDIO_DRIVE_TASKFILE` ioctl](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ioctl/hdio.txt) returned 0.</sub> 
²  <sub>Reading the source code of `hdparm` shows that this particular message is displayed when `sb[0] != 0x72 || sb[7] < 14 || desc[0] != 0x09 || desc[1] < 0x0c`. I have no idea what those numbers mean.</sub>

Comment: I don't care about the data on the disk. Is there something I can do so that I can read from anywhere on the "disk" again (after new data has been written, ofc)? Does a simple writing `dd` over the entire disk / the affected parts suffice? (I'm not sure whether you mean that it's likely that the bad blocks have been marked or that that should've happened but didn't.)

Comment: @UTF-8 I think once you remove the file you won't ”see“ the bad block again. But I wouldn't use a disk that's developed unreadable blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to

https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto

and

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Identify_damaged_files

for more information.

In a nutshell, after using tools like debugfs or sleuthkit to identify which file is damaged, and after `hdparm --read-sector`, you may try to use `--repair-sector` (alias of `--write-sector`) which "writes zeros to the specified sector number" and "force the drive to repair a bad sector (media error)"  See the hdparm man page for details.